# How to detect whether user has turned on developer options in android

Tags: android, react-native

I am building react native application and i want to detect  whether user has turned on developer options or not.
In MainActivity.java file, i'm always getting SettingNotFoundException exception.

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.provider.Settings.Global;
import android.provider.Settings.SettingNotFoundException;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     try {
       int devOptions = Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED);
     }catch (SettingNotFoundException e){
        Log.d(getClass().getName(),  "Called"); 
     }
 }
```

Comment: did you [read the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED) ?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code**

```
       try {
            int devOptions = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED);
            Log.d("DevOptions","Got Devoptions : "+devOptions);

        } catch (Settings.SettingNotFoundException e){
            Log.d(getClass().getName(),  "Called");
        }
```

And Use this import statement

```
import android.provider.Settings;
```

Comment: I tried this and this doesn't give exception but always returns 0(irrespective of developer options settings). Does this depends on android version because the solution to find out this way was given in 2013

Comment: Regarding its dependency on OS version. I don't think so . Which version are you trying on ?

Comment: Android Pie and later

Comment: Do you know any alternative way? or Why this is not working?